# Jmeter HTML reports from cmd but getting one request

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, automated-tests, load

I have 3 http request, if I run these test in jmeter and run cmd commend for reports I only get one http request please help me, I need all three in my report.

my http requests

[image: first image]

result

[image: second image]

And this is the cmd commend that I have used

```
jmeter -n -t "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin\project\softJmeterjson.jmx" -l "E:\softreportsa\r.csv" -e -o "E:\softreports\HtmlFolder\report1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm able to read I can see 3 sample results in the HTML Reporting Dashboard:

[image]

I would rather be interested in the reason for the remaining 2 sample results not having a label. You might want to check [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) (maybe with [debug level enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging)) file for any suspicious entries.

Also it might be the case you're looking at one of the previous results, try adding [`-f` key](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) to your command line so JMeter would replace [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=119548855) and HTML Reporting Dashboard with the results of the latest execution.